# Как запретить вставлять цифры в input type="text"?

Tags: javascript, html

Стала задача запретить ввод цифр в `<input type="text">` созданном для имени

Как можно такое реализовать?

Comment: Можно использовать событие `onkeypress`. Но зачем?

Comment: Задачи сами по себе не встают. Лучше бы знать контекст. Может вам ну самом деле input type=tel нужен

Comment: В частности у меня есть инпуты внутри формы в которые необходимо вставить текст, а в них могут поставить цифры и от этого непонятки при принятии данных с этой самой формы

Comment: Например на почту приходит вместо "Имя": Василий, к примеру, "Имя": 13542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function noDigits(event) {
  if ("1234567890".indexOf(event.key) != -1)
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="noDigits(event)" />
```

Comment: Отлично работающее решение

Comment: Его необходимо вставить в тег script перед инпутом или можно поставить в конец body?

Comment: @Кевин можно в конце. Имейте в виду, что это решение не защищает от вставки цифр через Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте атрибут `maxlength`.

```html
<input maxlength = "0">
```

Comment: В таком случае не будет возможно вставить вообще каких либо символов. А необходимо что бы нельзя было вставить только цифры

Comment: Аа. Ну в таком случае, разве что можно так: <input type="text" onkeyup="var yratext=/['0-9']/; if(yratext.test(this.value)) this.value=''"> но при таких условиях если ввести 0-9 то вся строка обнулиться.